# html form submit in navigation bar

Tags: html, forms, navbar

Need advice on html as i am not expert on this.
I need to display following form buttons on  a navigation bar on top of a web page but they are coming on different lines. I want this to be responsive so for smaller screens they adjust on different lines but if enough area , should display on nav bar in a single line. Tried few css but was not able to get it right. 
Suggestion....

```
<body class="body">     
    <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><form action="/create" ><button type="submit">Create</button></form></li>
                    <li><form action="/update" ><button type="submit">Update</button></form></li>
                    <li><form action="/delete" ><button type="submit">Delete</button></form></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
li, form { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Add CSS like this

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">     
    <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><form action="/create" ><button type="submit">Create</button></form></li>
                    <li><form action="/update" ><button type="submit">Update</button></form></li>
                    <li><form action="/delete" ><button type="submit">Delete</button></form></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
```